# Flatness of Chern classes for flat family of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces, chern-classes

Let $Q$ be a quasi-projective $k$-scheme (not necessarily smooth), $X$ a smooth projective $k$-variety and $\mathcal E$ a family of (torsion free) sheaves on $X$ parametrized by $Q$. Suppose that $\mathcal E$ is flat over $Q$. Can we find, for any $i\geq 1$, a cycle $Z\in CH^i(Q\times X)$ of class $c_i(\mathcal E)$ which is flat over $Q$? Is it easier if we add that $\mathcal E_q$ is globally generated on $X$ for all $q\in Q$?

Comment: There is a reduction to the case that $\mathcal{E}$ is locally free of finite rank using Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem. Also it suffices to prove the result for $\mathcal{E}(m)$ with $m\gg 0$ using the following identity in the K-group of the projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$ in which $X$ embeds: $\sum_r \binom{n+1}{r}(-1)^r[\mathcal{O}(m+r)] = 0$.  Also, using Whitney sum, it suffices to prove the result for $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{E}(m)\oplus \mathcal{O}(m)^{\oplus N}$ for $N\gg 0$.   Now use Thom-Porteous.  You need to prove, ala Bertini, that degeneracy loci of $\mathcal{F}$ are flat over $Q$.

Comment: ... Finally, to prove the degeneracy loci of $\mathcal{F}$ are flat over $Q$ (for general choices of global sections of $\mathcal{F}$), you will probably use Eagon-Hochster.

Comment: You might check if Gabber-Liu-Lorenzini have proved something about this; they proved results that sound similar to this.